# .NET 5 CORE MVC: Trying to import a module from a JavaScript file, always results in a console error. The file is never found under the wwwroot folder

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-5, asp.net5

I'm trying to implement the Bootstrap 5 version of the Table Editor plugin of MDBootstrap, but the error that I get, has nothing to do with them, at least, not directly. This is my first time working with modules so bear with me. What I'm trying to achieve, is simple. This is the header of my importer js file:

```
import FocusTrap from './mdb/util/focusTrap';
import PerfectScrollbar from './mdb/perfect-scrollbar';
import { getjQuery, typeCheckConfig, onDOMContentLoaded } from './mdb/util/index';
import Data from './mdb/dom/data';
import EventHandler from './mdb/dom/event-handler';
import Manipulator from './mdb/dom/manipulator';
import SelectorEngine from './mdb/dom/selector-engine';
import tableTemplate from './table/html/table'; //eslint-disable-line
import { getModalContent, getModal } from './table/html/modal';
import {
  search,
  sort,
  paginate,
  getCSSValue,
  formatRows,
  formatColumns,
  getRowIndex,
} from './table/util';
```

Great. Well, this code produces the browser error:

[image: Browser Imports Error]

So of course, my JS plugin doesn't work because the browser doesn't find the imports. I suspects is because I'm not using the `~` at the start of the path to indicate that they resides under the wwwroot folder. However writing the `~` in front of the path, causes yet another error by the browser, saying, that's incorrect syntax.

So I'm stuck!!!

In case you are wondering, this is how my wwwroot looks right now:

[image: wwwroot structure]

And the Table Editor js file, which is the one that does the import, is right there alongside those folders:

[image: wwwroot structure 2]

What should I do in this situation?

Help :(

Comment: Hi @SamyCode, where is your `importer` js file located?

Comment: Hello @Rena. Thank you for your willingness to help. The js that does the import is called "table-editor" and is right there alongside the other folders from which it tries to import. You can check it out and see it in the last screenshot of my question.

Comment: Hi @SamyCode, I got it. The first line(`import FocusTrap from './mdb/util/focusTrap';`, ) as a example. Firstly, when you use `./`, it will search the `table-editor.js` location. So  FocusTrap module request url is : `mdb/src/plugins/table-editor/js/ mdb/util/focusTrap` (You can F12 and put the mouse to the focusTrap, it will show you the request url. Also it is the entire path for your module. You can see here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOa0H.png ) . Secondly, it seems the `focusTrap` is a folder not a js file. Be sure specific the file name: `'./mdb/util/focusTrap/filename.js'`.